# Should juice be drunk slowly, to allow it to mix with  saliva?

Tags: nutrition

A meme about eating fruit did the [rounds of the Internet](http://www.google.com/search?q=If%20you%20drink%20the%20juice%2C%20drink%20it%20mouthful%20by%20mouthful%20slowly%2C%20because%20you%20must%20let%20it%20mix%20with%20your%20saliva%20before%20swallowing%20it.) in 2009-2010. It included this claim:

> If you drink the juice, drink it mouthful by mouthful slowly, because you must let it mix with your saliva before swallowing it.

While chewing is good for starchy foodstuffs, is it any good for liquid, sugary juices?

Comment: that would only help in cases were saliva is needed which would only be for starch and fats wiki ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saliva#Digestion